# I need to export the list of IDs of the satellite images available in Google Earth Engine to work in Excel. I just need the ID

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat, landsat-8, gvsig

I am working with Google Earth Engine and I need to export the collection as a list, to be able to work it in Excel. What I mean is being able to export the list of the ID of the available satellite images of any Landsat, that is located in the console of Google Earth Engine. What I need is just this Ej: LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_TOA/LT05_001083_19860204.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That text can be found as the property `system:id` of each image. To get it as a CSV, export the collection as a table and specify just the one property name:

```
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: imageCollection,
  fileFormat: 'CSV',
  selectors: ['system:id'],
});
```